# How to add pagination to FilterView

Tags: django, django-filter, django-pagination

I've filtering view of django_filters.FilterSet which is called right from `urls.py`

```
url(r'^$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=ProductFilter, template_name='products/products.html'), name='products'),
```

and it's has no pagination, but when i add `paginate_by = 20` in

```
url(r'^$', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=ProductFilter, template_name='products/products.html'), paginate_by = 20, name='products'),
```

it adds my custom pagination page, but it's not handling data restricted by filters. So i can apply a few filters and it reduces data to, say 40 rows, but clicking on a second page it loads my all data without any filter. Could I specify that I want to paginate data after filtering somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I decided to create separate view and add queryset directly to context object like:

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/products.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['product_list'] = ProductFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.order_by('id')).qs
        return context
```

Comment: How did you manage to keep the filter form in your view? I'm trying to follow your solution. I can get the pagination but I lost the filter form.

Comment: `{% for page_num in paginator.page_range %}` this is how i can get a paginator object in template and `product_list` as object containing filter.

Comment: This is so in-conclusive answer.

Comment: also pass the form through context `context['form'] = context['product_list'].form`

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be much simpler to achieve pagination with filters on a given view:

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/products.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(my_field=my_criteria)
```